# Clone a element with events not working, if the cloned element is inside different container

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

I have cloned a element using jQuery clone function

```
oldEle = $( "#BVRRSummaryContainer .bv-submission-button.bv-write-review" );
newEle = $( "#BVRRSummaryContainer .bv-submission-button.bv-write-review").clone(true, true);
newEle.appendTo( "#BVRRSummaryContainer" );
```

**Not Working Case:**
I'm cloning oldEle to newEle with events. when the new element is appended to a different container which the oldEle does not belong click event is not happening.

**Working Case:**
If I append the newly created element in the same container which oldEle belong, click event works

But I need to place the newEle in a different container.

Comment: It might be because of the selector that you used for the click event. Can you show it?

Comment: Could you include how the event handlers are attached to oldEle?

Comment: It sounds like you may be using a delegated event handler which is attached to the container of the `oldEle`, not the `newEle`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan just my thought too.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I dont have control of the event which comes from a third-party plugin. Is there anyway to copy the event irrespective of the way it is nested?

Comment: Not if the event is attached to a parent element, no. You would need to make a clone of the parent container too, but be aware that this could have odd side-effects in the behaviour of the plugin depending on how the logic is structured.